# Defining new or redefining existed custom method of System Object

Tags: powershell

Friends, how can I define new custom methods of System Object or redefine existed ones?

```
# Example of using Add-Member cmdlet:
Add-Member -InputObject [System.Array] -MemberType "ScriptMethod" -Name "joinSpaces" -Value {return $This -join " "}

# Check the method added:
[System.Array]::joinSpaces -eq $Null  #=> True
[System.Array].joinSpaces -eq $Null  #=> True
("a", "b").joinSpaces -eq $Null  #=> True
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: Hello @AnsgarWiechers . I just want to know if there is anyway that I can extend a `type` in Powershell. If there is noway to do that, I will using `[PSCustomObject]` like normal.

Comment: That was already clear to me from your question. I'm asking *why* (for what purpose) you think you need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To define new members at the *type* level rather than at the *instance* level, you must use `Update-TypeData`** rather than `Add-Member`:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Array -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName JoinSpaces `
  -Value { $this -join ' ' }
```

<sup>To force *redefinition*, append `-Force`.</sup>

This makes the method **available to all future *instances*** of type `[System.Array]`.

To see it in action:

```
PS> ('one', 'two').JoinSpaces()
one two
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

By passing `[System.Array]` to `-InputObject`, you passed *string literal* `'[System.Array]'`, not the array *type*, because in *argument*-parsing mode a token that starts with `[` is interpreted as a *string*, not an expression.

To pass a *type*, you would have had to use `-InputObject ([System.Array])` - note the `(...)` - but that would attach the `joinSpaces()` method to the *object* representing the *type itself*, and not *all instances* of that type.

In other words, you would have been able to do the following, although that is not of much use:

```
PS> [System.Array].joinSpaces()
System.Array
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

```
[PSCustomObject]$PSCustomObject = @{Name='MyPSCustomObject';DataSet=@()}

Add-Member -InputObject $PSCustomObject -MemberType 'ScriptMethod' -Name 'JoinSpaces' -Value {return $This.DataSet -join ' '} -PassThru

$PSCustomObject.DataSet = 'a','b','c','d','e'

$PSCustomObject.JoinSpaces()
```

Output:

```
a b c d e
```

Comment: The question looks to me like they want to extend a *type*, not an *object*.